# Why are Qt resources being loaded in Linux but not Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to load some PNG icons and some text files into my Qt program created in Qt Creator via a qrc file, but while the respective images appear on the toolbar (as they should) in the UI editor and in Linux, the buttons are blank when compiled in Windows. I even tried

```
QImage img(":/icons/debug.png");
qDebug() << img.isNull(); // true
```

I have my source files and the .pro file in basedir/src/, and the resources and .qrc file in basedir/src/res/

Is there something I'm doing wrong? If so, why does this work in Linux but not Windows?

EDIT:

```
qDebug() << QImageReader::supportedImageFormats(); // ("bmp", "cur", "dds", "gif", "icns", "ico", "jpeg", "jpg", "pbm", "pgm", "png", "ppm", "svg", "svgz", "tga", "tif", "tiff", "wbmp", "webp", "xbm", "xpm")
```

Here is my qrc file.

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/icons">
        <file>sphere-icon.png</file>
        <file>project-properties.png</file>
        <file>debug.png</file>
        <file>qsi-icon.png</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/dictionaries">
        <file>Enums.txt</file>
        <file>LegacyFunctions.txt</file>
        <file>MiniSphereObjects.txt</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: execute this: `qDebug()<<QImageReader::supportedImageFormats();` in windows

Comment: Show your .qrc file

Comment: Build/Clean All, Build/Run qmake, Build/Rebuild All, Run

Comment: @scopchanov I tried that several times, with no change.

Comment: I have experienced exactly the same problem several times and running qmake resolved it for me. Are you sure you're executing qmake after clean?

Comment: I did, and all of the commands you listed several times and in different orders.

Comment: That's  strange. Could you create a small example and share it to play a bit?

Comment: Or if you wish, I could create one for you and send it. Then tell me if it is working for you, and depending on the result we will discuss further. Does it sound OK?

Comment: https://github.com/scopchanov/ResourceTest

Comment: The link is a very basic example project which works on my machine (Qt 5.9.1, MSVC 2017, Windows 7). I have also created the same folder structure as you've described. So, please try it and if it works we have to seek the problem elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, it works there, though img.isNull() returns true. I even created a new form in my project to see if something was going wrong with my .ui file, but it still had the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152355/discussion-between-josh-and-scopchanov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I don't know why this worked, but after cleaning and rebuilding a hundred more times, deleting the .pro.user file, deleting my temporary folders (which I set in the project file to keep things more organized), removing the .qrc file reference from the project file, then restarting, suddenly everything works